# Integração do TSF com Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, team-foundation-server, integração

Gostaria de saber se alguém já realizou ou sabe como realizar a integração do Android studio com o TSF. Até o momento só encontrei formas de integras com o IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio é baseado na versão **Community Edition** do Intellij IDEA. A integração com TFS assim como outras várias funcionalidades, só estão disponíveis na versão **Ultimate Edition** do Intellij IDEA, que não é a base para Android Studio.

Provavelmente você só conseguirá fazer essa integração fazendo as associações manualmente pelo Visual Studio ou linha do comando.

Answer (score 0):

A integração existe, você não vai ter todas as funcionalidades na IDE, mas pode usar o Web Portal, ou seja, interface Web.

- **Código**

  Não conheço Android Studio, porém, sei que ele é nativamente integrado ao Git, e hoje o TFS ou o VSTS (antigo VSO) aceitam criar repositórios Git; inclusive o VSTS aceita ter em cada projeto 2 tipos de repositórios, Git como TFVC. Quando você fizer um commit você pode usar #[Número do WorkItem] na mensagem e o TFS fará a integração do commit com os artefatos, normalmente Tasks.
- **Artefatos**

  A criação de WorkItems (Tasks, User Storys/Product Backlog Items, Features, ...) deverá ser feita via Web Portal, inclusive algumas features já nem estão mais no Visual Studio, já que a Microsoft está se movimentando para que o TFS/VSTS seja visto como uma ferramenta que atende qualquer plataforma, linguagem, etc...
- **Build**

  Com a atual versão 2015 do TFS e no VSTS, você poderá fazer builds de código Android, hoje está mais simples, "scriptado", e você pode escrever os steps em Node.js, se os existentes não atenderem.